# Ansible import task with boolean true or false

Tags: ansible

I want to make a deployment task/role with a boolean. By default is a false and make it a true, the deployment is done. Like a variable in main.yml is defined

```
vars:
  - c

- name: task 1
  import_tasks: "a.yml"
  when: c is defined
  tags:
    - a

- name: task 2
  import_tasks: "b.yml"
  when: c is defined
  tags:
    - b
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following; however, as noted in one of the comments below, this can cause some unexpected behavior in certain circumstances and is not the only way to achieve what you’re asking:

```
- set_fact: c=false
  when: c is undefined

- name: task 1
  import_tasks: "a.yml"
  when: c | bool
  tags:
    - a

- name: task 2
  import_tasks: "b.yml"
  when: c | bool
  tags:
    - b
```

Comment: You don't need to `set_fact` here. `when: c | default(false) | bool` as a condition will do the job. Note that your example will break on occasions like when e.g. setting `c` to `true` as an extra var: `ansible localhost -m debug -a msg="{{ c is true }}" -e c=true` gives `false` while `ansible localhost -m debug -a msg="{{ c | default(false) | bool }}" -e c=true` evaluates to `true` as expected.

Comment: Fair enough.

Regarding the debug example, is that the only case where that occurs or would there be others?

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I have got an error
{"msg": "The conditional check 'c is true' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: no test named 'true'. String: {% if c is true %} True {% else %} False
 {% endif %}

Comment: I have got a mistake : msg": "The conditional check 'c | bool' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (c | bool): 'c' is undefined

Comment: When testing locally, this works for me without issue. Did you add the set_fact task properly? 
I see in your follow up post you have
```set_fact: c is false``` Make sure set_fact says ```set_fact: c=false```

Comment: yes, I male it sure, but it works withtout set_facts and when condition is when: c | default(false) | bool

Comment: @aaron This will break anytime `c` is evaluated as a string rather than a boolean and there are many occasion on which it can happen. This is why [ansible-lint as a specific rule for that](https://ansible-lint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/default_rules.html#don-t-compare-to-literal-true-false) and also why you should always use the `bool` filter to make sure user provided truthy values are always interpreted correctly even when coming in as strings.